# Count number of rows matching >1 criteria

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns, as follows:

```
A<-c(4,4,4,3,2,4,1)
B<-c(4,4,2,31,3,1,1)
data<-data.frame(A,B)
```

I know I can use **grep()** to search for the number of times a row matches one criteria (e.g. **length(grep(4,A))** would count that there are 4 times theres a 4 in column A.

How can I get R to count the number of rows that match TWO criteria--e.g. "how many rows have a "4" in column A *AND* a "2" in column B.

```
C<-c("hat", "hat", "coat")
D<-c("shoe", "sock", "glove")
data2<-data.frame(C,D)
```

Ideally, I'd like something that can work for strings too. In this instance, e.g., how many rows contain "hat" in C and "sock" in D?

(This is essentially the equivalent of the **COUNTIFS** function in Excel.)

Comment: How does your expected output look like? Do you want `1` since there is only one row that contains `hat` and `sock` or do you want `2` for column `C` and `1` for column `D`?

Comment: Update: I was able to make it work on a toy example using "sum(data2$C=="hat"&D=="sock"), but for some reason, this doesn't work when I do it with my real data. str( ) tells me it's a 'data.frame': 34 obs. of  2 variables: 
 $ trialType       : Factor w/ 3 levels "learn","practice",..: 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ chosen_task_type: Factor w/ 2 levels "control","procedural": 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 ...) It will tell me 'Error: object 'chosen_task_type' not found' when I try sum(myData$trialType=='learn'&chosen_task_type=='control') ---maybe it's because the data type is "factor"??

Comment: @MartinGal I was looking for the first instance. Counting the number of rows where there's both "hat" and "sock", yeilding a return value of "1".

Comment: I think your code should be `sum(myData$trialType=='learn' & myData$chosen_task_type=='control')` to work.

Comment: @MartinGal Ahh, you're right! Thank you so much!      .....strange that it worked for the "data2" example as "sum(data2$C=="hat"&D=="sock")" but not the other data.

Comment: It worked on the `data2` example because there was indeed an object named `D` which (since data2 was defined by `D`) had the same structure as `data2$D`. In your _real example_ I believe, there was no `chosen_task_type` vector/object.

Comment: Hmm @MartinGal it breaks down if I add an "NA" criteria. sum(myData$chosen_task_time!='NA' & myData $trialType=='learn' & myData$chosen_task_type=='control'), returning: "[1] NA" instead of some count.

Comment: You are checking for a string containing `"NA"`. If you want to check for _real_ `NA`'s use `R`'s `is.na()`-function, so in your case: `sum(!is.na(mydata$chosen_task_time) & mydata $trialType == 'learn' & mydata$chosen_task_type=='control')`.

Comment: Ah, that's right. Thanks again!

Comment: Take a look at Park's `dplyr` based answer. This one might simplify things for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  filter(A == 4, B == 2) %>%
  nrow

[1] 1

data2 %>%
  filter(C == "hat", D == "sock") %>%
  nrow

[1] 1
```

where

```
data %>%
  filter(A == 4, B == 2)

  A B
1 4 2

data2 %>%
  filter(C == "hat", D == "sock")

    C    D
1 hat sock
```